# OutOfMemory when manipulating images

Tags: processing, out-of-memory

This produces an OutOfMemory exception after running for a few seconds. Any ideas?

```java
PGraphics img;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  img = createGraphics(width, height, JAVA2D);

  // this is here just for the testcase because else I get a
  // NullPointerException too (probably a harmless Processing bug)
  img.beginDraw(); img.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  PGraphics tmpImg = createGraphics(img.width, img.height, JAVA2D);
  tmpImg.beginDraw();
  tmpImg.image(img, 0, 0);
  tmpImg.endDraw();
  tmpImg.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It could be possible that you have a Memory Leak somewhere. This could be found with a good Analyser software or a really good debugger.

Comment: Are you really supposed to create a new PGraphics every time you enter draw?

Comment: img.Dispose?...

Answer (score 2):

Mat's right, you're not supposed to instantiate a new PGraphics each frame.
You could simply do something like this:

```
PGraphics img;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  img = createGraphics(width, height, JAVA2D);

  // this is here just for the testcase because else I get a
  // NullPointerException too (probably a harmless Processing bug)
  img.beginDraw(); img.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

because [PGraphics](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html) extends [PImage](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PImage.html).
Typically you'd use the [basic PImage API](http://processing.org/reference/PImage.html), but if you'd need to draw shapes onto a bitmap or fake 'layers', you could use PGraphics in conjunction with PImage, but just don't allocate a new PGraphics 30 to 60 times a second.